# I have two eclipse projects on a SVN repository. How should I combine them into one?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, merge, subversive

I have two eclipse projects on an SVN repository that I feel should be merged into one.
The easiest way that I can think of doing this is to copy the contents of both projects into a new local project, commit it, and nuke the old ones.

Is there a better, SVN-ish way of doing things?

I'm using the Eclipse Subversive plugin, for what its worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy the files locally then add them to Svn as new content, you lose all the continuation in the history of your files - don't do that.

Better reorganize the files directly within the repo. I don't know Subversive, but e.g. TortoiseSVN allows this.